# Why is Sentry.captureMessage not working inside winston Transport log function

Tags: javascript, typescript, sentry, winston

I’m trying to get Sentry working with [winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston) (using [winston-transport-sentry-node](https://github.com/aandrewww/winston-transport-sentry-node/)) but it doesn’t seem to work, despite using just a very basic configuration. So out of curiosity, I tried writing my own very simple winston transport class that sends Sentry message for every log like so

```js
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/node'
import * as TransportStream from 'winston-transport'

export class SentryCustomTransport extends TransportStream {
  constructor(opts) {
    super(opts)

    Sentry.init({
      dsn: process.env.SENTRY_DSN,
      environment: process.env.ENV_NAME,
      sampleRate: 1,
      tracesSampleRate: 1,
    })
    Sentry.captureMessage('Test message constructor')
  }

  log(info, callback) {
    setImmediate(() => {
      this.emit('logged', info);
    })

    console.log('Called log function')
    const eventId = Sentry.captureMessage('Test message log')
    console.log('Event ID:', eventId)

    callback()
  }
}
```

After calling winston logger, I can see an entry in Sentry with message "Test message constructor" but not "Test message log". What's even weirder is I can see the console log prints, including the event ID returned from the calls to `Sentry.captureMessage()` in the `log()` function.

I'm not sure what's going on, and kind of have no idea how to make it work. What am I missing here?

winston version: 3.8.2
@sentry/node version: 7.37.2
winston-transport-sentry-node version: 2.7.0

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the cause of the issue myself. The context of my issue was I'm writing a CLI command in NestJS. Part of the command's implementation (rather incorrectly) include a call to `process.exit()` function which immediately terminates the command without giving it a chance to do proper clean up (and flushing of data). I'm guessing it's because of this the Sentry module didn't get the chance to actually push the created Sentry event to Sentry server.

Removing the calls to `process.exit()` and letting the command finishes normally resolves the issue.